# How to search for a word within string

Tags: python

I'm trying to search for a word within string.

Example

```
match = 'File'
s2 = 'name of File: is .jpg'
if match not in s2:
   print 'ok'
```

And it worked. Can I do this with `list`?

```
match = ['File','Category']
```

Comment: Do you want to search for exact words? I. e., if your search word is `foo`, do you want it to match the `foo` within `foobar`?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker  not exact words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can. So we check for each word in `match` if that word is there in `s2` or not.

```
for word in match:
    if word not in s2:
        print 'ok'
```

or a simple one-liner -

```
[word for word in match if word not in s2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just seeking for existence of a word:

```
>>> 'St' in 'Stack'
True
```

If you are seeking for its position also:

```
>>> ("stack").find("st")
0
```

Note: The content below has been fetched from http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html  while the content above is tested original creation of mine for your kind reference:

**Syntax:**

```
str.find(sub[, start[, end]])
```

Shall Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found, such that sub is contained in the slice s[start:end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. Return -1 if sub is not found.

**Reference:**

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html <-- Read to know more variety of methods for more focused searching

Answer (score 0):

```
for entry in match:
  if entry not in s2:
    print 'ok'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s2.split()
['name', 'of', 'File:', 'is', '.jpg']
>>> s = s2.split()
>>> s[2]
'File:'
>>> match in s[2]
True
```